# Adding an Eclipse menu contribution to another view

Tags: eclipse, view, menu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've a view that I want to add a menu contribution to, however I do not have the source code for the view's plugin.  I wrote another plugin, and have this as my `plugin.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.5"?>
<plugin>

  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <category id="myplugin.category" name="myplugin.category"></category>
    <command id="myplugin.command" name="myplugin.command" categoryId="myplugin.category"></command>
  </extension>

  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handler">
    <handler commandId="myplugin.handler" class="com.package.mypluginclass"></handler>
  </extension>

  <extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution
      locationURI="menu:com.package.otherpluginview?after=additions">
      <command
        commandId="myplugin.handler"
        label="Load/Save Column Configuration">
      </command>
    </menuContribution>
  </extension>

</plugin>
```

My entry does not display, however it is there if I step through with the debugger (using test code).  Does anyone see what I might be missing?

Comment: Contribution to what menu? Do you know that is the menu id or are you just guessing? Do you know the menu has an 'additions' location?

Comment: The view menu (drop-down next to the minimize bar).  My assumption was the that the menu id is the name of the view, but I'm not sure.  Your questions, however, did give me a new idea to solve my problem.  I looked at the plugin's `plugin.xml` file, saw how the existing menu items are listed, and formatted mine to suit.  My menu id guess was right, but I was missing other entries.  I'm working now.  Thanks.